# Practical Schema Design in Mongoose for list of articles/topic in the homepage and for each full detail articles/topic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in Mongoose and trying to create my first DB on it,

Here is my problem

I had created a Tour Schema for one Travel Site for my Node.js API project.

Two parts in the frontend will get data from that Model:

- the homepage that has the list of tours

  and
- the detail page for each specific tour.

Here is the JSON file

```js
  {
    "name": "some name",
    "type": "Bestseller tour",
    "image-thumbnail": "https://cdn.vuetour.com/images/cards/docks.jpg",
    "rating": 4.3,
    "duration": 4,
    "transportation": "plane",
    "reviews-count": 25,
    "price": 6999,
    "reviews":[
         "Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. What else can I say? Quick, thorough, excellent.",
         "Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. What else can I say? Quick, thorough, excellent.",
         "Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. Excellent work. What else can I say? Quick, thorough, excellent."
    ],
    "timeline": [
      {
        "day": 1,
        "title": "Day 1: Arrive and meet the Group",
        "description": [
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        ]
      },
      {
        "day": 2,
        "title": "Day 2: Beaches, Temples & Sunsets",
        "description": [
           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        ]
      },
      {
        "day": 3,
        "title": "Day 3: Learn to Surf",
        "description": [
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        ]
      },
      {
        "day": 4,
        "title": "Day 3: Learn to Surf",
        "description": [
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        ]
      },
      {
        "day": 5,
        "title": "Day 3: Learn to Surf",
        "description": ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        ]
      }
    ]
  },,
  },
```

Should I need to divide into 2 collections:

- 1 for some short information that I need in the homepage list of tours - such as name, price, rating, reviews-count, etc.
- 2 is the long detail values for each specific detail tour page - such as timeline, review, etc.

If divide like that, I have to query DB 2 times for one detail tour page - get short data and long data,

Or I just to create just one collection for all of that data above?

I saw in the [Realworld Node.js Project](https://github.com/gothinkster/node-express-realworld-example-app/blob/master/models/Article.js) they just create one Article Model to store all the data,

```js
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  slug: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  title: String,
  description: String,
  body: String, // long string data for the content of the blog
  favoritesCount: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  tagList: [{ type: String }],
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

And when we get the list of articles at the homepage, all the data has sent back to the user - even some long long body of the article that is hidden!

So what is the solution in the real-life project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not add two separate collections, I would use just one and send back via API only the needed data. You can use GraphQL if you want to segment super specifically the data you send back.

But in terms of Mongo architecture I have never heard of separating collections.

Comment: So I will use 1 collection as normal, and try to figure out about GraphQL later, thanks for your answer.